# How can I view a live Starcraft II match in-game?

Tags: starcraft-2

When I watch screencasts of Starcraft II, I notice that there are people leaving the game at the end that weren't part of the match. How do I spectate a Starcraft II match?

Comment: If i can't watch it live... would'nt be nice if u could "watch the aftermatch replay"like when u see your personal replays ? Anyway, just a wish. I like to watch great players.

Comment: Have You tried googling "starcraft 2 spectator"? There are several theories, for example: a) [joining the games makes You one](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/939643-starcraft-ii-wings-of-liberty/54497328) b) [host enables spectators](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20100917170014AAYrnQq) and [only in private games](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/939643-starcraft-ii-wings-of-liberty/54497328) c) ["click a match thats full and you enter spectator mode"](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20100917170014AAYrnQq) ...

Answer (score 9):

I believe that currently the only way is to get invited (as in, there isn't a list of available games to watch somewhere)

Obviously ladder games cannot be watched, but you can watch custom games if it's set to allow watchers, and the creator adds you to them.

Comment: Indeed. And it's a good thing that observers must be invited, because they can introduce lag to the game, causing a nuisance.

Comment: *I'm silently hoping we can watch games over the spectate protocol in the future, it would make it a lot more fluent (rather than seeing a low quality video that lags) and allows much more detail. It can be easily implemented if you forward the game to one server which spreads it to a hierarchy of servers/watchers.*